# Seeing occasional crash on OpenTok iOS when a phone call is being answered during an OTSession

Tags: ios, opentok

According to the docs, OpenTok should be releasing the AudioSession on receiving interruption notifications in iOS. Sometimes it doesn't or it get's dealloced some how. Any ideas as to what the issue may be? Here's the crash:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS: Attempted to dereference garbage pointer 0xff57565eff55540c.

0  libEmbeddedSystemAUs.dylib   InterruptionListener(void*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void const*)
1  AudioToolbox                 AudioSessionPropertyListeners::CallPropertyListeners(unsigned int, unsigned int, void const*)
2  AudioToolbox                 HandleAudioSessionCFTypePropertyChangedMessage(unsigned int, unsigned int, void*, unsigned int)
3  AudioToolbox                 ProcessDeferredMessage(unsigned int, __CFData const*, unsigned int, unsigned int)
4  AudioToolbox                 _ASCallbackReceiver_AudioSessionPingMessage
5  AudioToolbox                 __XAudioSessionPingMessage
6  libAudioToolboxUtility.dylib _mshMIGPerform
7  CoreFoundation               ___CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
8  CoreFoundation               ___CFRunLoopDoSource1
9  CoreFoundation               ___CFRunLoopRun
10 CoreFoundation               _CFRunLoopRunSpecific
11 AudioSession                 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*)
12 AudioSession                 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*)
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib      __pthread_start
```

Comment: How are you declaring the property for the audio session?

Comment: yes, please do share a snippet if you can, I will share this with the eng team.

Comment: We aren't directly interacting with audio session. All we do is OTSession.connect, publish, and subscribe. That all works fine, but when a call comes in, we occasionally hit this crash.